# Validating only visible sections of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get this working for days and am just going around in circles, no matter what resource I read. I think I'm going to have a ton of errors in my code but I just can't figure it out.
I've got a form that I'm wanting to break down into smaller parts, on the click of a next button it will validate all the data in that section then hide it and show the next section. I've also got the issue of my form adds in sections depending on if the person has a partner or children. I'm not sure on how to handle that so would really appreciate some tips.

Here's my validation function, the jfiddle for the full code is below

```
$(".next").click(function() {
$('#travelform').find(":visible").find("input[required]").each(function(){
    var myPattern = $(this).attr('pattern');
    var myPlaceholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    var isValid = $(this).val().search(myPattern) >= 0;
    var isEmpty = true;

    var abort = false;
    $("div.error").remove();

    //traverse through each required field to ensure it's been filled in
    $(':input[required]').each(function() {
       if($(this).val()==='') {
           $(this).after('<div class="error">This is a required field</div>');
           abort = true;
       } 
    });
    if (abort) { return false;} else {return true;}
});
```

});

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gq4kyhs3/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a class to all the inputs that have been validated and have a value and then check for this each time next is pressed like this:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
$('#travelform').find(":visible").find("input[required]").each(function(){
    var myPattern = $(this).attr('pattern');
    var myPlaceholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    var isValid = $(this).val().search(myPattern) >= 0;
    var isEmpty = true;

    var abort = false;
    $("div.error").remove();

    //traverse through each required field to ensure it's been filled in - Added this check in to see if it has already been checked...if not then continue...

    if ($(this).hasClass('checked-and-filled') {
       $(':input[required]').each(function() {
          if($(this).val()==='') {
              $(this).after('<div class="error">This is a required field</div>');
              abort = true;
          } else {

             // if the value is not empty then we know its been checked and it has a value
             addClass('checked-and-filled');

          }
       });
       if (abort) { return false;} else {return true;}
    }
});
```

Also a quick comment about your HTML. I noticed this in your fiddle but I think you might have this error in your actual code...

On all of the part sentences you start with a `h3` tag but end with a `h2`:

```
<h3 class="center">Part 1 of 5</h2>
```

Comment: It was in my HTML, thank you for that! The validation doesn't do anything when I click on the next button, should I be adding something else to the pages as well?